# How to use coroutines to alternate printing between two lists?

Tags: python, list

I have two short lists in python and I am a beginner. If anyone could assist me in writing coroutines that make my lists alternate by printing one item at a time, it would be of great help.

```
cars = ['BMW', 'Benz','Tesla']
veggies = ['Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Spinach']
for item in cars:
    print(item)

for item in veggies:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to use coroutines to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
cars = ['BMW', 'Benz','Tesla']
veggies = ['Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Spinach']
for i in zip(cars,veggies):
    print('\n'.join(i))
```

Or:

```
cars = ['BMW', 'Benz','Tesla']
veggies = ['Broccoli', 'Carrots', 'Spinach']
for x,y in zip(cars,veggies):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Both will be alternating the two lists

Coroutines are not useful, needed here

If list have different lengths do:

```
import itertools
for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(cars,veggies):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Comment: I think you should at least mention that you (apparently) don't think coroutines are necessary. I also think your code would be better it it handled lists which were not both the same length.

Comment: @martineau How about now

Comment: @martineau Edited again

Comment: Does me adding code to make each list print items a random amount of times change your opinion?

Comment: @Kaylah: You could use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to introduce delays between `print()` function calls.